# How can I sync two computers with dropbox and not have one delete a new file?

Tags: dropbox

I want to have two laptops syncing to the same dropbox account. When both laptops are running and a new file is uploaded, the other laptop downloads it straight away and all is synced.

The problem is that when the laptop I am not working on is Off, and I upload a new file to dropbox with my other Laptop, then when I switch on the laptop that was off it begins indexing. It sees that online there is a newly uploaded file and on itself (the laptop) it isnt there. It then proceeds to delete it from online thinking I must have deleted it from my second computer.

How can I make it understand that it has to download missing files rather then deleting new ones?

Comment: That sounds like a bug with Dropbox. Dropbox should have enough event timeline data between the online space and the laptop to know that the file was added *after* the last update. Have you asked this question in the [Dropbox support forums](https://www.dropbox.com/help)?

Comment: Maybe the clocks and timezones are not correct on these two machines.